# Парсинг и конвертация тестового XML файла в файл формата YAML на языке Python

Tags: python, парсер, xml, конвертация, yaml

**Здравствуйте!** Нужна помощь с написанием нормально работающей программы конвертера XML в YAML .

Сделать это нужно при помощи языка Python. **Нельзя  использовать  готовые  библиотеки,  в  том  числе  регулярные выражения в Python и библиотеки для загрузки XML-файлов.** Встроенные модули разрешены!

**1**. На руках есть файл формата XML .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<timetable>
    <lang> ru </lang>
    <day> Wednesday </day>
    <lessons>
        <lesson1>
            <teacher> Балакшин Павел Валерьевич </teacher>
            <time> 08:20-09:50 </time>
            <group> ИНФОРМ 3 </group>
            <room> Актовый зал </room>
            <place> ул.Ломоносова, д.9, лит. М </place>
            <subject> ИНФОРМАТИКА (ЛЕК): АКТОВЫЙ ЗАЛ</subject>
            <lesson-format> Очно-дистанционный </lesson-format>
        </lesson1>
        <lesson2>
            <teacher> Клименков Сергей Викторович </teacher>
            <time> 10:00-11:30 </time>
            <group> ОСН ПРОФ ДЕЯТ 1 </group>
            <room> Актовый зал </room>
            <place> ул.Ломоносова, д.9, лит. М </place>
            <subject> ОСНОВЫ ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ (ЛЕК) : АКТОВЫЙ ЗАЛ</subject>
            <lesson-format> Очно-дистанционный </lesson-format>
        </lesson2>  
    </lessons>
</timetable>
```

**2**. Нужно преобразовать его в файл формата YAML, чтобы программа создала новый файла с только что полученным YAML внутри:

```
timetable:
  lang: ru
  day: Wednesday
  lessons:
    lesson1:
      teacher: Балакшин Павел Валерьевич
      time: '08:20-09:50'
      group: ИНФОРМ 3
      room: Актовый зал
      place: 'ул.Ломоносова, д.9, лит. М'
      subject: 'ИНФОРМАТИКА (ЛЕК): АКТОВЫЙ ЗАЛ'
      lesson-format: Очно-дистанционный
    lesson2:
      teacher: Клименков Сергей Викторович
      time: '10:00-11:30'
      group: ОСН ПРОФ ДЕЯТ 1
      room: Актовый зал
      place: 'ул.Ломоносова, д.9, лит. М'
      subject: 'ОСНОВЫ ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ (ЛЕК) : АКТОВЫЙ ЗАЛ'
      lesson-format: Очно-дистанционный
```

Сделать это нужно при помощи языка Python.
Что самое весёлое, **нельзя  использовать  готовые  библиотеки,  в  том  числе  регулярные выражения в Python и библиотеки для загрузки XML-файлов.** Встроенные модули разрешены!

Есть пример кода, который неправильно работает:

```
fin = open('schedule.xml', encoding='UTF-8')
fout = open('schedule_out.yaml', 'w+')
fout.write('---\n')

read = 0
word = ''
for line in fin:
    xml = line
    yaml = ''
    for i in range(len(xml)):
        if read != 2 and xml[i] == '\t' or xml[i] == ' ' or xml[i] == '\n':
            yaml = yaml + xml[i]
        elif xml[i] == '<':
            if xml[i + 1] != '/':
                read = 1
            else:
                read = -1
        elif xml[i] == '>':
            if read == 1:
                yaml = yaml + ': '
                read = 2
            elif read == -1:
                if word != '':
                    if not word.isnumeric():
                        yaml = yaml + '"' + word + '"'
                        word = ''
                    else:
                        yaml = yaml + word
                        word = ''
                read = 0
        elif read == 1:
            yaml = yaml + xml[i]
        elif read == 2:
            word = word + xml[i]
    fout.write(yaml)

fout.write('\n...')
fout.close()
```

Вывод такого недокода:

```
---
?xml version="1.0"?: 
timetable: 
lang:   "   ru"
    day:   "Wednesday"
    lessons: 
lesson1: 
teacher:     "                  БалакшинПавелВалерьевич"
            time:   "08:20-09:50"
            group:    "ИНФОРМ3"
            room:    "Актовыйзал"
            place:      "ул.Ломоносова,д.9,лит.М"
            subject:     "ИНФОРМАТИКА(ЛЕК):АКТОВЫЙЗАЛ"
            lesson-format:   "Очно-дистанционный"
        
        lesson2: 
teacher:     "          КлименковСергейВикторович"
            time:   "10:00-11:30"
            group:      "ОСНПРОФДЕЯТ1"
            room:    "Актовыйзал"
            place:      "ул.Ломоносова,д.9,лит.М"
            subject:        "ОСНОВЫПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ(ЛЕК):АКТОВЫЙЗАЛ"
            lesson-format:   "Очно-дистанционный"
            
    

...
```

Буду признателен, если поможете!

Comment: Чем не нравится вывод скрипта?

Comment: Посмотрите, как должен выглядеть код, это можно увидеть в самом начале

Comment: А почему модуль string использовать можно, а модуль re или xtree нельзя? Или иначе,  что можно использовать? Как работать  с текстом не используя модуль string.

Comment: Извините, я имел в виду библиотеки или модули для парсинга или представления xml файлов, к встроенным модулям это не относится! Изменю вопрос тогда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот +- рабочий парсер, наверно с багами, надо тестить, но тот тест кейс, который вы прислали проходит

```
PUNCTUATION = r"""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""


def get_open_tag_name(s: str) -> str:
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == '>':
            return s[:i+1]

    raise ValueError('Key not found')


def get_close_tag_name(s: str) -> str:
    return s.replace('<', '</')


def get_text_without_tag(text: str, open_tag: str, close_tag: str):
    result = text.replace(open_tag, '').replace(close_tag, '').strip()

    if result:
        if not result.isalnum() or not result.isascii():
            result = f'\'{result}\''

    return result


def get_yaml_content(lines) -> str:
    open_tags = []

    yml_content = []
    for row in lines:

        tab_lenght = '\t' * len(open_tags)
        tmp_row = row.strip()

        if tmp_row[0] == '<' and tmp_row[1] not in PUNCTUATION:
            open_tag = get_open_tag_name(tmp_row)
            close_tag = get_close_tag_name(open_tag)
            text = get_text_without_tag(tmp_row, open_tag, close_tag)

            if tmp_row[-len(close_tag):] != close_tag:
                open_tags.append(close_tag)

            yml_content.append(f'{tab_lenght}{open_tag[1:-1]}: {text}')

        elif tmp_row[0] == '<' and tmp_row[1] == '/':
            if open_tags[-1] != tmp_row:
                raise ValueError('Bad XML file')
            open_tags.pop()

    if len(open_tags) != 0:
        raise ValueError('Bad XML file')

    return '\n'.join(yml_content)


def main():
    with open('test.xml', mode='r') as f:
        xml_lines = f.readlines()

    yaml_content = get_yaml_content(xml_lines)

    with open('test.yml', mode='w') as f:
        f.write(yaml_content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вывод

```
timetable: 
    lang: ru
    day: Wednesday
    lessons: 
        lesson1: 
            teacher: 'Балакшин Павел Валерьевич'
            time: '08:20-09:50'
            group: 'ИНФОРМ 3'
            room: 'Актовый зал'
            place: 'ул.Ломоносова, д.9, лит. М'
            subject: 'ИНФОРМАТИКА (ЛЕК): АКТОВЫЙ ЗАЛ'
            lesson-format: 'Очно-дистанционный'
        lesson2: 
            teacher: 'Клименков Сергей Викторович'
            time: '10:00-11:30'
            group: 'ОСН ПРОФ ДЕЯТ 1'
            room: 'Актовый зал'
            place: 'ул.Ломоносова, д.9, лит. М'
            subject: 'ОСНОВЫ ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ (ЛЕК) : АКТОВЫЙ ЗАЛ'
            lesson-format: 'Очно-дистанционный'
```

Comment: единственное не понял по какому принципу у вас значение оборачиваеться в одинарные ковычки, поэтому оборачивал все, что не буква и не ascii

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: Одинарные кавычки не несли в себе какой-то смысловой нагрузки